# Using a build system for reproducible research?

Tags: build-system, reproducible-research

I am doing a research project that involves a pipeline of programs, each generating an output file that becomes the input for the next program. I would like to make it easy to repeat the series of commands that I used to create the desired output. It seems like *make* or any other build system would be a good fit for this task, but all the build systems that I've looked at (except for maybe *make* itself) seem to be strongly biased toward building executabe files from source code, and I can't figure out how to do anything else with them. Does anyone have experience using a build system for tasks other than compiling source code into executables? Can I easily use a build system to facilitate reproducible research, or should I be looking for a different kind of tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured this out by myself eventually. I'm using plain old (GNU) Makefiles.